# Execute code after a function call response in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am a beginner in Nodejs and express.
I need to call a function and after its execution need to proceed with the response. Used **promise** for this process but it wont work.
My code is

```
var NodeGeocoder = require('node-geocoder');
const Promise = require('bluebird');
var geocoder = NodeGeocoder(options);

function getArea(req, res) {

   let row=1;
   let col=1;
   let startingLat = req.body.starting_lat;
   let startingLng = req.body.starting_lng;
   let distance = req.body.distance;
   var resp = false;
   while(resp !=true){ 
     let input = [];
     input.lat = startingLat;
     input.lng = startingLng;
     input.distance = distance;
     input.row = row;
     input.col = col;
     saveZone(input).then(function(responsse,err)  {                
                if(responsse){
                    //some code 
                    row++;                   
                }

            }).catch(function (err) {                    
                console.log('error',err);                    
            });

    }
    res.json({
            status: 200,
            message: "success"
        });

}

function saveZone(input, callback) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // some code      
      resolve(result);
    }
}

/**
Export all methods
*/
module.exports = {
  getArea: getArea,
  saveZone:saveZone
};
```

I am calling **saveZone** function inside the **getArea** function. Need to wait for the response and then determine if the while loop need to exit. Referred many questions on stackoverflow but still i can't.Please help me to solve this

Comment: In this case either you have to use `async` `await` function or you have to put the `res.json` inside of the `then` function of `saveZone`.

Answer (score 0):

Your response will get returned before even the promise is resolved, you have to wait for the promise to return the response if you want the response only after the promise resolution. Please find the code below:

```
function getArea(req, res) {
      // ... your code
     saveZone(input).then(function(responsse,err)  {                
                if(responsse){
                     res.json({
                        status: 200,
                        message: "success"
                     });               
                }

            }).catch(function (err) {                    
                res.json({
                        status: 500,
                        message: "error"
                     }); 
            });

    }

}
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: i need to call saveZone function repeatedly inside `while` loop until the response return and after some conditions return true. after that only i can use `res.json`